# Does smell count as a detectable sense?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

At the start of the game Ocelot tells you to be wary of all of the senses of the enemy soldiers. Then, throughout the game you are reminded to take showers.

I'm wondering if you do not shower, it states you will have both **physical** and mental effects. Would a physical effect be a smell?

If you think about blood giving off a stench after time and also sweat. Would this attract enemy soldiers?

Comment: I don't know about smell, but a few effects of showering include: longer Reflex time, and faster healing. One thing I know, is that no matter how bloody Snake is, soldiers won't notice him approaching from behind, even if he hasn't showered in a very long time. However, if Snake stays hidden in dumpsters for too long, he'll attract flies and trigger a "Snake stinks" cutscene. Maybe soldiers will notice him then, but I'll need to test it out to be certain.

Comment: Soldiers definitely have a "what's that smell?" reaction; I've seen them do it a few times, including issue some VO lines. I'm not sure they were doing it because of *me* though.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**. Enemies can smell you and will try to find the source if you are nearby. Animals can even think that you are dead (it can be helpful if you are hunting). [This is what they do when you smell bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bnIX16r9bk).

**Source:** [IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/09/18/100-little-details-in-metal-gear-solid-5-that-will-blow-your-mind)